# Loop optimization in QB64

Tags: basic, qbasic, qb64

Have a loop in QB64 concerning loop optimization:

```
DIM N AS DOUBLE, X(100000000) AS DOUBLE
T! = TIMER
FOR N = 1 to 100000000
    IF X(N) THEN
        PRINT X(N)
        EXIT FOR
    END IF
NEXT
PRINT TIMER - T!
```

is it any faster than:

```
DIM N AS DOUBLE, X(100000000) AS DOUBLE
T! = TIMER
FOR N = 1 to 100000000
    IF X(N) <> 0  THEN
        PRINT X(N)
        EXIT FOR
    END IF
NEXT
PRINT TIMER - T!
```

EDITED: 09-18-2018 to include variable types

Comment: Insufficient information.  What type is "N?" What type does function "X" return?  Can't you simply use a timer and test this yourself?

Comment: I did a timer test on the two routines and they return the same exact time to the millisecond.

Comment: How many iterations does it perform before exiting the loop?

Comment: This may be your answer: "I did a timer test on the two routines and they return the same exact time to the millisecond." - You

Comment: @Bill: Since the array is defined with 100000000 elements to zero, all of them.

Comment: I saw that after I posted the question, I was going to delete my comment.  That's quite a few iterations.  Like Robert said, I think you've answered your own question, then.  Apparently there's no difference in time, at least not measurably.  Perhaps the qb64 compiler is highly optimized and the results would be different on other platforms.

Comment: Yes, most likely due to the optimization of the translated to GNU C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I written this code to evaluate your test:

```
REM Delete REM to enable console runs
REM $CONSOLE:ONLY
REM _DEST _CONSOLE

DIM SHARED N AS DOUBLE, X(100000000) AS DOUBLE

S# = 0: ZC% = 0
T% = 10
IF COMMAND$ <> "" THEN
    T% = VAL(COMMAND$)
END IF

IF T% > 999 THEN T% = 999

FOR I% = 1 TO T%
    A# = TRYA
    B# = TRYB

    D# = A# - B#
    PRINT USING "Case A ... : #.########"; A#
    PRINT USING "Case B ... : #.########"; B#
    PRINT USING "Diff ..... : #.########"; D#;

    A$ = ""
    IF ABS(D#) < 0.00000001 THEN
        ZC% = ZC% + 1
        A$ = "*"
    END IF

    S# = S# + A# - B#

    PRINT A$
    PRINT

    REM INKEY$ doesn't work in console mode!
    A$ = INKEY$
    IF A$ = CHR$(27) THEN
        I% = I% + 1: EXIT FOR
    END IF
NEXT

PRINT USING "Avrg A - B : #.########"; S# / (I% - 1)
PRINT USING "0 diff:### on ### tryes"; ZC%, (I% - 1)
PRINT

PRINT "Hit a key to exit!"
REM INPUT$ doesn't work in console mode!
A$ = INPUT$(1)
SYSTEM


FUNCTION TRYA#
    T# = TIMER
    FOR N = 1 TO 100000000
        IF X(N) THEN
            PRINT X(N)
            EXIT FOR
        END IF
    NEXT
    A# = TIMER - T#

    TRYA = A#
END FUNCTION

FUNCTION TRYB#
    T# = TIMER
    FOR N = 1 TO 100000000
        IF X(N) <> 0 THEN
            PRINT X(N)
            EXIT FOR
        END IF
    NEXT
    A# = TIMER - T#

    TRYB = A#
END FUNCTION
```

The two different routines are inserted into two functions: `TRYA` and `TRYB`.

I launched this SW with a loop that runs 999 times the functions and the result is:

```
Avrg. A - B: 0.00204501
0 diff:359 on 999 tryes
```

then I launched with a 10 times loop and the result is:

```
Avrg. A - B: -.01640625
0 diff:  1 on  10 tryes
```

then I launched with a 15 times loop and the result is:

```
Avrg. A - B: 0.00026042
0 diff:  5 on  15 tryes
```

Cause we launch the SW in a multi-thread ambient I don't believe this is a very good test, but there's some results:

1. In two cases the results of no difference (0 diff) is a third of all loops.
2. In two cases it seems the function `TRYA` is slower.
3. In one case it seems the function `TRYB` is slower.

Looking at these results, I think, we may consider the two functions equivalent!

You obtain more than 10 loops running the code from command line (or modifying the command$ parameter into the QB64 menu) as:

`# ./test n`

Where `n` is the number of loops you desire.

The SW was compiled using gcc with -O3 optimizations option. (To do this you have to modify the file `[/opt/]qb64/internal/c/makeline_lnx.txt`)

Comment: Thanks for the test! I thought there would be little or no difference...

Comment: I think there's no difference because the simplest (only) way to compile `if value` should be based on `if value<>0`.

Comment: Or if the compiler optimizes `if value<>0 then` to `If value then`

Comment: If you go in very low level you may immagine that in asm x86 you have (in both case) the same code, roughly: `cmp ds:[ebx],0; jnz label; call printf; label: ...`

Comment: I would think the C++ compiler optimizes C=C+1 and C+=1 and C++ as well.

Comment: @eoredson. In modern compilers the optimizations go far beyond the simple syntax behaviour that you indicate. In assembler x86 all operations you wrote above will be written with something as: `inc ds:[ebx]` or `inc eax`. One optimization may be the compiler choices between the two instructions I indicated a little above.